# Why cin.fail() doesn't return false when entering a number followed by character?

Tags: c++, cin

I wrote this simple code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   double s;
   cin >> s;
   if (cin.fail())
     cout<<"Error";
   return 0;
 }
```

When I enter `12.03`, `cin.fail()` returns `false`, and that's good.

And when I enter `sd234`, `cin.fail()` returns `true`, which is also good.

But if I enter `234.abcd`, for example, or any number followed by a characters, `cin.fail()` returns `true` although I didn't enter a numerical to the `double` variable through the `cin`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean `cin.fail()` returns *`false`* in the first case and *`true`* in the second?

Comment: I think your entire true, false thing is wrong. It should be returning the exact opposite than what you are saying.

Comment: Why would it fail? It's a _stream_ of data, and the characters after the extracted number are ready for the next read attempt. By your logic, a stream would only ever work for one, single extraction, which would be pretty silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's why I'm asking, in order to know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::istream::operator>>()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) reads characters as long as it fits to the current type (e.g. digits and . for `double`). Following characters are left in the input buffer for another extraction operator. If the characters read can satisfy the current type, no error is signaled.

Answer (score 1):

Because it reads `'234.'`, and that's a valid number.
The rest of the stuff that you've entered, `'abcd'` is waiting for the next read.

Answer (score 1):

The input asked for, i.e., a `double` coukd be satisfied, i.e., the read operation was successful. If you want to check that the stream continues with something you'd expect you need to read this. Alternatively you can check if the next character in the stream is of a certain kind.